# Write a symbolic Matlab function which varies depending on its argument

Tags: matlab, function

I can write symbolic functions like this:

```
syms A B x X
y1(x) = A
y2(x) = B
```

How can I write a function such that `y(x) = x<X ? y1(x) : y2(x)`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't have Symbolic Math Toolbox, but you may try this:

```
y(x) = (x<X)*y1(x) + (x>=X)*y2(x)
```

Comment: This pretty much works, but apparently the better solution is to use the difference of pairs of `heaviside` functions. They will follow `assume` use. Thanks for this though - upvoted since allowed me to get some messages out of Matlab which lead me to the alternative solution

Comment: @chrisb2244 If you have a solution to this, Its better you write it as an answer, or if you still want to give CST the credit, edit his answer to add the information. The idea of SO is that the knowledge stays after the question have been solved!